# getting error when doing the composer install

Tags: 8

Drupal version was 8.6.2 and moved to new server.
When doing the core update , getting an error like below.

```
 Problem 1
- remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)|remove drupal/core 8.6.3
- don't install drupal/core 8.6.2|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- don't install drupal/core 8.6.3|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- don't install drupal/core 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- don't install drupal/core 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- don't install drupal/core 8.6.3|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- Installation request for drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
- Installation request for drupal/core ^8.6.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev]
```

i have tried the composer install by removing composer.lock, vendor and core. Still getting same error.

Updated with my composer.json

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/core": "^8.6.2",
    "drush/drush": "^9.2",
    "drupal/s3fs": "^3.0",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "^1.4"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
        "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
        "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
        "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
    ],
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the composer error messages are really opaque: Took me the whole day to figure this one out. And stil am not sure how to debug the composer related problems (and I have read all the drupal documentation, lots of composer documentation, so maybe I am just losing IQ points lately...)

**Error 1: composer install**

I had the same problem on *composer install* (Clive removed my earlier remark) and thought the culprit was

*remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)*

Couldn't figure out why that would happen: Added all modules neatly with require bladiebla and had no problem updating core to 8.6.4

Site was running smoothly

**Error 2: install module**

Trying to install backup_migrate resulted in the error

*The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting*

Which I also did not understand because my minimum stability was *dev* and the backup_migrate version was a stable one

Trying different things to find out where the problem originates did not bring any solution

*composer install*
*composer update*
*composer diagnose*
*composer why*
*composer give me a break*
*etc*

Is supposed that one of the modules I required conflicted with another one, but how to find out which one..... (any hints on how to debug these composer message are welcome)

**SOLUTION (in my case)**

In the end I simply did this

*starting point*

drupal 8.6.4

minimum stability dev

php 7.0.3

*actions*

1. remove core, modules/contrib, vendor, composer.lock
2. in composer.json:

2.1 start with (in my case)

```
    "drupal/core": "~8.6.0",
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
```

2.2 in the following require part require all advised highest version for all modules you use (so go to the drupal mordules site en copy the advised composer require statements)

```
   "drush/drush": "~9",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": " ^4.0",
    "drupal/backup_db": " ^1.1",
    "drupal/draggableviews": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/pathauto": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/token": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/anonymous_redirect": "^2.2",
    "drupal/ctools": " ^3.0",
    "drupal/calendar": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/geolocation": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_taxonomy_term_name_depth": "6.x-dev",
    "drupal/views_templates": "^1.0",
    "drupal/paragraphs": " ^1.5",
    "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
    "drupal/webform": " ^5.0",
    "drupal/social_login": " ^2.83",
    "drupal/disqus": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/address": " ^1.4",
    "drupal/leaflet": " ^1.0",
    "drupal/geofield": "^1.0",
    "drupal/geophp": "^1.0",
    "drupal/geocoder": "^2.0",
    "drupal/geofield_map": "^2.20",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0",
    "drupal/addtoany": "^1.10",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^1.29",
    "drupal/field_group": " ^3.0"
```

3. run 
   composer install
4. go to your site and run www.domain.ext/update.php

That resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the composer.json in drupal core, I think you have an old composer.json setting, here composer.json drupal 8.6.7 :

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.6"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit phpspec/prophecy symfony/yaml --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```